# Sending Hex value in Javascript over Net

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do the following thing in JavaScript:

1. I have value which i get in runtime, for example: 2acdabcd
2. This value is a memory address, i am trying to convert it to Hex to this: \x2a\xcd\xab\xcd
3. Then i combine this with the following value: "abcd"+ address
4. Then i send this to my application
   My question is, what is the best way to send it, in such case it will send the address as is and it will not be changed, for example , in the Hex value it will be:  616263642ACDABCD

Comment: Do you want to send a string?

Comment: Hi, Yes, i want in the end , when i send it to remote server, i will see in the Hex this string 616263642ACDABCD

Comment: So all you want to know is how to convert `abcd` to  `61626364`? Because the address that you already have doesn't change.

Comment: No, i want the address i send will stay as is , The address is not hardcoded in the code

Comment: Exactly, you want it to stay as is, so there's no problem with that?

Comment: Yes, do you have any idea ?

Comment: I mean you should convert the `abcd` prefix to hex format before, and *then* concatenate the dynamic address input (that already is in hex format)

Answer (score 0):

If the address value you have is number type and the prefix is ​​always the same, can you do it as follows?

```
const address = 0x2acdabcd
console.log(address)             // -> 718121933

const address_str = address.toString(16)
console.log(address_str)         // -> "2acdabcd"

const target_address_str = '61626364' + address_str
console.log(target_address_str)  // -> "616263642acdabcd"
```